# Let $\alpha$ be a cut and $r\in\Bbb Q^+.$ Then $\exists p\in \alpha$ and $q\in\alpha ^c$ such that $q$ is not the least element of $\alpha^c$ and

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I was studying real analysis. I recently got to know the definition of a *cut*. The definition goes as follows:

> A set of $\alpha$ of rational numbers is said to be a cut if : (i) $\alpha\neq \emptyset, \alpha\neq \Bbb Q$ (ii) if $p\in\alpha$ and $q\in \Bbb Q$ with $q<p$ then $q\in\alpha$ (iii) if $p\in \alpha$ then $\exists q\in\Bbb Q$ with $q>p$ such that $q\in\alpha.$  The condition (ii) shows that if $\alpha$ contains a rational number then it contains all rational number preceeding it. The third condition shows that the set has no largest rational. If $\alpha=\{x\in \Bbb Q: x<r \space \text{and}\space r\in\Bbb Q\}$ then $\alpha$ is a cut and we denote $\alpha=r^*.$

I encountered the following lemma:

Let $\alpha$ be a cut and $r\in\Bbb Q^+.$ Then $\exists p\in \alpha$ and $q\in\alpha ^c$ such that $q$ is not the least element of $\alpha^c$ and $r=q-p.$

The proof given is as follows:

> Let $s\in \alpha$ be any element. Look at the elements $s_n=s+nr,n\in\Bbb N.$ As $\alpha$ is bounded so, $\exists m\in\Bbb N$ such that $s_m=s+mr\notin \alpha.$ Let $T=\{k: s_k\notin \alpha\}.$ Then $T$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb N.$ By well-ordering property $T$ has a least element say $n_0.$ Then, $s+n_0r\in\alpha^c$ and $s+(n_0-1)r\in \alpha.$ If $s+n_0r\in\alpha^c$is not the least element of $\alpha ^c$ then we may take $q=s_{n_0}$ and $p=s_{n_0-1}$ so that $q-p=r.$ If $s+n_0r\in\alpha^c$ is the least element of $\alpha^c$ then we may take $q=s_{n_0}+\frac r2$ and $p=s_{n_0-1}+\frac r2$ so that $q-p=r.$ Thus, we can express any positive rational number as the difference of an upper member( not least) and a lower member of any given cut.

However, in the above proof, I do not get, how can they make the statement, " If $s+n_0r\in\alpha^c$ is the least element of $\alpha^c$ then we may take $q=s_{n_0}+\frac r2$ and $p=s_{n_0-1}+\frac r2$ so that $q-p=r.$" I mean, what if $p=s_{n_0-1}+\frac r2\notin \alpha$ ? How are they so sure, that $p=s_{n_0-1}+\frac r2\in \alpha$ ? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: Well this is part of special case when $s_{n_0}$ is least element of $\alpha^c$ and then any rational number less than $s_{n_0}$ lies in $\alpha$. Note that $s_{n_0-1}+(r/2)=s_{n_0}-(r/2)<s_{n_0}$.

Comment: The proof is full of symbolism and it is best to convert the proof into natural language. Take any member of $\alpha$ and keep on adding $r$ to it till you reach a member of $\alpha^c$. In this way you get a list of numbers in which there is a last which belongs to $\alpha$ and the next one in list lies in $\alpha^c$.

Comment: Handle special (and easier) case when $\alpha^c$ has a least member $m$ by choosing $p=m-(r/2),q=m+(r/2)$.

Comment: Most of such arguments in analysis are made complicated by overuse of symbols (perhaps to intimidate students).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks a lot! I do get it now. Yes, what you said is so true in some cases. I agree with you completely!